# how can i change the style in calendar for single day in node.js ejs

Tags: css, node.js, calendar

I want to make some of the day bold inside calendar,
lets say I want the 10 and 15 of the month to be bold

```
dateTitle.datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [true, "custom-day"];
    }});
```

but nothing happens, its not adding class to the td.

I tried to find the td my self,
but I dont know how to run my function, after the calendar is shown,
the calendar table is not visible most of the time, only when clicked

pls help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the style for specific days in your calendar that you work with EJS and Node.js, here are the steps:

- Pass the special dates you need (eg 8th or 10th and 15th or 19th of a special month you need) from the Node.js to the EJS template.
- In the EJS template, iterate over the days in the calendar and see if each day is one of the special dates you need.
- If a day corresponds to a special date, apply a custom CSS class to it. Otherwise, use a default class.

This is a Node.js sample code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Special dates
const specialDates = [10, 15];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('calendar', { specialDates });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is a Template EJS sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calendar Example</title>
  <!-- Include necessary CSS and JS libraries for your calendar here -->
  <style>
    /* Define your custom styles for special days */
    .special-day {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="calendar">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <% for (let day = 1; day <= 31; day++) { %>
          <td class="<%= specialDates.includes(day) ? 'special-day' : '' %>"><%= day %></td>
          <% if (day % 7 === 0) { %>
            </tr><tr>
          <% } %>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- Include necessary JavaScript for your calendar here -->
</body>
</html>
```

We need to transfer the specialDates array we created to the EJS template, which contains the numbers corresponding to the dates we need (such as 14 or 15 or 10 or 19).
Within the EJS template, we iterate over the days using a for loop. We use the specialDates.includes(day) condition to check if the current day is one of the dates we need. If this is what we need the date to be, we apply the "special day" class to the  element; Otherwise, we do not apply additional classes.
I mean you can customize the "special day" class in the  section to define how special days should appear. In this example, we made the text bold and red (a random color I decided).
Don't forget to include all the CSS and JavaScript libraries necessary for the look and functionality of your journal.
This should allow you to format specific days in your calendar as needed. Adjust the code according to your specific calendar application and style preferences.